# Django QuerySets - Related Models

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a set of related models - main points included below:

```
class OrganisationDetails(models.Model):
FormFieldOrgID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
FormFieldOrgCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Organisation Code',
                                    help_text='Enter organisation identifier', default='NULL', )
FormFieldOrgName = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter Organisation Name',
                                    verbose_name="Organisation Name")  

class DepartmentDetails(models.Model):
FormFieldID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
FormFieldDeptName = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text='Enter Department Name',
                                     verbose_name="Department name")  # name for a department
FormFieldDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter department description ',
                                        verbose_name="Department description")  # describe the department

class OrgDeptLink(models.Model):
FormFieldID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
FormFieldDeptID = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='DepartmentDetails',
                                    verbose_name='Department', help_text='Select department')  # department
FormFieldOrgID = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='SubordinateRole',
                                   verbose_name='Organisation', help_text='Select organisation') 

class OIRLinkStakeholders(models.Model):
    FormFieldOIRStakeLinkID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False)
    FormFieldOIRStakeholderID = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                  help_text='Select Internal Stakeholder',
                                                  verbose_name='Stakeholder ID')  # TODO Set list to Organisation Departments
    FormFieldOIR = models.ForeignKey(OIROverview, help_text='Select OIR Document Name', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     verbose_name='OIR ID')  # TODO Default to be set to  a selected organisation
```

I would like to get: FormFieldDepartmentName from class DepartmentDetails(models.Model) using pk from Orgdetails - extract from views.py:

```
def oirdetails(request, pk):
orgdetails = OrganisationDetails.objects.filter(FormFieldOrgID=pk)
oiroverview = OIROverview.objects.filter(FormFieldOrgDetailID=pk)
alldepartments = OrgDeptLink.objects.filter(FormFieldOrgID=pk)
currentstake = OIRLinkStakeholders.objects.filter(
    FormFieldOIRStakeholderID__DepartmentDetails__FormFieldOrgID_id__exact=pk)
```

The variable for currentstake is the one im trying to relate to:
[ive include a snapshot of the relationships below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG3J3.jpg)

Ive had a look at the documentation - but cant grasp the concept of ORM in django "yet".

ANy advice most welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
currentstake = OIRLinkStakeholders.objects.filter(
    FormFieldOIRStakeholderID__DepartmentDetails__FormFieldOrgID_id__exact=pk)
```

was correct but in template had to use currentstake.FormFieldOIRStakeholderID_id